# Geometric series problem, finite sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\sum\limits_{n = 10}^{40} \left(\frac{1}{8}\right)^n$$

I do not know the steps to finding the sum of this problem.

I know the general formula is 
$$ = a_1\frac{1 - r^n}{1 - r}.$$

[Wolfram alpha link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sigma+%281%2F8%29%5En+n%3D10+n%3D40)

Comment: Please add the left side of the equation for the "general formula".

Answer (score 3):

You could do this two ways: pull out a factor of $\left(\frac{1}{8}\right)^{10}$ from the sum
$$\sum_{n=10}^{40}\left(\frac{1}{8}\right)^n$$
to make
$$\left(\frac{1}{8}\right)^{10}\cdot\sum_{n=0}^{30}\left(\frac{1}{8}\right)^n$$
(and this new sum you should know how to do), or you can write the sum
$$\sum_{n=10}^{40}\left(\frac{1}{8}\right)^n$$
as a difference
$$\sum_{n=0}^{40}\left(\frac{1}{8}\right)^n\;\;-\;\;\sum_{n=0}^{9}\left(\frac{1}{8}\right)^n$$
(and again, each of these two sums you should know how to do).